# How to draw "bell-curves" in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, graph, equalizer, bell-curve

I'm making an equalizer graph with a Flutter.

But with the "Custom Paint" class drawPath, Bezier Curve (quadratic BezierTo),
I kept failing to create a graph that looked exactly like the picture.

When I searched, I saw that I had to use something called a bell curve.

How can I draw that graph?

Please, Please help me.

[image]
[image]

If I'm wrong please tell me how to draw that nice equalizer graph. Using a flutter!

I tried making "Equalize graphs" using canvas.drawpath method(cubicTo, quadraticBezierTo).

But nothing was the same.